# How to translate with JQuery using id in the window and translations from an object?

Tags: jquery

I have a pivot table with id in the `<TH>` and I wondering how I can use these id to get translation.

using this

```
$('th').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == '1234') { $(this).text('MyTranslationWithId1234'); }
});
```

My object would be this:

```
{1234: 'text1234'},
{3232: 'text2332'},
{3278: 'text3278'}
```

I have about 500 id in `<th>` and I would like to translate them directly using JQuery

Comment: `<th>` is a column _header_. Do you really have 500 columns? Please post an example of your HTML

Comment: Yes its a huge matrix using sometimes 500 column by 2000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a strange way to do it, I would just use one object with keys, and not multiple objects, like so :

```
var translation = {
                   1234: 'text1234',
                   3232: 'text2332',
                   3278: 'text3278'
                  };

$('th').text(function(_,txt){ return translation[parseInt(txt,10)]; });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jqKmc/)

Otherwise you'll have to do a lot of slow iterating :

```
var translation = [
                    {1234: 'text1234'},
                    {3232: 'text2332'},
                    {3278: 'text3278'}
                  ];

$('th').text(function(_,txt){ 
    var key = parseInt(txt,10);

    $.each(translation, function(_, obj) {
        if ( key in obj) txt = obj[key];
    });

    return txt;
});
```